# grails removeFrom not working in Integration Test

Tags: grails, integration-testing

All of this is on Grails 2.2.3.

I have two classes in a One-to-many relationship, and a service which removes a list of ids

```
class Box {
  String name
  static hasMany = [items:ItemDomain]

  static constraints = {
    items(nullable:true)
  }
}
```

and

```
class ItemDomain {   String name   Box box

  static belongsTo = Box

  static constraints = {
    name(blank:false,unique:['box'], maxSize:127)
    box(nullable:false)   } }
```

In the service, here's the problem section:

```
def itemsToDelete = params.itemsToDelete   //List of DB ids
List<ItemDomain> items= []
items.addAll(box.items) //Copy the list to avoid concurrent mod exception
for(ItemDomain item : items)
{
  if(itemsToDelete.contains(item.id))
  {
    box.removeFromItems(item)
    item.delete()
  }
  box.save(flush: true)
}
```

This works fine when running the application, but from integration testing it fails with

```
InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)
```

If I take out the flush, and eventually it will fail with:

```
 Field error in object 'mypackage.ItemDomain' on field 'box': rejected value [null];
```

Adding logging, I see the size of box.items before entering the loop is the same as it is after exiting the loop, printing the items in the loop before and after shows that the item.box field for the deleted items changes to null.  I've tried messing with the cascade mapping in the parent class...  I'm at a loss as to whether I'm doing something wrong or if this is an issue with integration testing.  The only similar issues I found were against grails 1.1 and had no resolution in the threads that I found.

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: First remove from box then save box then delete item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, not surprisingly, I was doing something wrong.  It turns out that my equals() and hashCode() implementations on the ItemDomain class were including a field that was never supposed to change, but due to requirements creep, was now changing and the methods never got updated properly.